# Calling a website url inside my react native app and redirect to app again on completion of file download

Tags: android, react-native, webview, deep-linking, inappbrowser

I have a requirement in my project where a user has to go to an external website from app to download a file.After downloading the file,he should be redirected to the app again.My app is built on **react-native**.Can anyone suggest a novel way to deal with this problem.
**A case in point:In food delivery apps,the users will be redirected to app after making the payment through payment gateway which is an external website**.

I have tried **Webview,Linking.openURL,InAppBrowser**,but none of them were able to redirect to app on download of file

Comment: If you have the event on the website where the file is being downloaded. Then you can use deep linking. 

- After downloading the file. Open the URL of the app use deep linking 

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#linking--module